# Create a vector of grid with Gtkmm

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am working with the library [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/) in C++. But I wonder if I can create a vector of a `Grid` for instance? I mean in C++ I can create a vector of `int` and add an element dynamically with the method `push_back()`. Is it possible to do the same with Gtkmm?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors have template parameters.

Just do something like that:

```
#include <gtkmm/grid.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<Gtk::Grid> myGridVector;
//          ^^^^^^^^^^
//          This is the template parameter
```

You could replace this template parameter with any other concrete type and you'll have a vector of that type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of any type you want in C++. Of integers, floats, enums, structs, classes, etc. Your `Grid` is a class, and as such, you can create a vector of that. See torkleyy's answer for an example.